# document.object Vs. document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these two syntaxes below-

**`document.object`** and **`document.getElementById()`**.

I want to know **when to use which syntax**???

e.g.-

### CODE1(Implementation with `<form>`)

```
<body onload="document.forms[1].innerHTML='hi';">//Alt: onload="document.getElementById('f1').innerHTML='hi';"
<form id=f1>
    <input />
</form>
<form id=f2>
    <input />
</form>
</body>
```

both the syntax in `onload` works the same way. But this doesn't work for the following-

### CODE2(Implementation with `<div>`)

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='hi';">//cannot use the syntax: onload="document.divs[1].innerHTML='hi';"
<div id=div1>hello</div>
<div id=div2>hello</div>
</body>
```

So definitely the syntax: **`document.object`** does not work with `<div>`-elements but works with `<form>'-element. But **`document.getElementById()`** works for both. So when should I use which one???

Someone please highlight the differences between the two syntaxes.

Thanx in advance...

Comment: i would use IDs whenever possible to separate the JS from the cgi.

Comment: Can you always guarantee what position your form will be in in the DOM?

Comment: please, correct formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.forms` is a very old method of accessing stuff, along with `document.images` and `document.all`, and possibly a few others that I don't remember.

The number one flaw in accessing `document.forms[1]` is simple: what if another form is added to the page, before the target one? Suddenly you have to search through all your code for references to anything, and change them.

This is where IDs come in. By only allowing one of each ID on a page, `getElementById` can accurately retrieve it, every time, without caring about what happens to the document in the meantime. The only change that matters is the element being removed altogether.

Comment: he's not talking about index access, he;s talking about named access, in which case a name collision is just like an ID collision...

Comment: `onload="document.forms[1].innerHTML='hi';"` Looks like index access to me.

Comment: `object_name` in the title clearly refers to the tag name. OP is under the impression that because `document.forms` works on `<form>` elements that this reasoning applies to `<div>` elements in `document.divs`. Of course, this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **document.object_name** to find anchors, applets, embeds, forms, images, links, plugins.

to find HTML Elemets like div, span, etc. you have to use selectors. you can get this elements by element name, id, class, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access the div in your example is via the "named access on window object" functionality (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object):

Instead of

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='hi';">
```

you can use

```
<body onload="div1.innerHTML='hi';">
```

Note that "div1" is a property of the window object, not of the document object.

Comment: This has had spotty browser support.