# is document.FORMNAME in W3C Standard?

Tags: javascript, standards, w3c

Many peoples are coding as `document.FORMNAME`. more than `document.forms.FORMNAME`.

sure. it works in any browsers.

also, `document.FORMNAME.FIELDNAME` is most using style. not `document.forms.FORMNAME.elements.FIELDNAME`.

is it W3C Standard? I can't find any similar references.

anybody can explain me?

Comment: use `document.getElementsByTagName('form')`

Comment: Look at [document.object_name Vs. document.getElementById()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163481/document-object-name-vs-document-getelementbyid)

Comment: Still, you should use `document.forms.FORMNAME.elements.FIELDNAME` for clarity, (future) compatibility and quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does, in the HTML5 spec, under "Supported property names" of the document and form objects.

See http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-namedItem-which for the form names on the document onkect

and http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#htmlformcontrolscollection for the field names on the form controls collection.

Comment: Thanks. but for old browser compatibility(except IE), we wouldn't use `document.FORMNAME` yet, because it's not supported in XHTML browsers.